# How to sort a list in descending order along with group by?

Tags: mysql, database, sorting

In rails 4 application, I am trying to fetch some data by combining more than one table.

`SELECT keywords.name, DATE(keyword_histories.created_at) as c, position, keyword_id FROM 'keyword_histories' join keywords on keywords.id = keyword_histories.keyword_id WHERE (keywords.website_id = 3716 and keyword_histories.status = 'finished') AND ('keyword_histories'.'created_at' BETWEEN '2020-03-16 00:00:00' AND '2020-05-15 00:00:00') GROUP BY DATE(keyword_histories.created_at), keyword_histories.keyword_id  ORDER BY keywords.name asc, keywords.id asc, keyword_histories.created_at desc, DATE(keyword_histories.created_at) desc;`

Current output for this query is(first few lines are taken here),

```
+---------+------------+----------+------------+
| name    | c          | position | keyword_id |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+
| az      | 2020-05-08 |        1 |       3360 |
| bags    | 2020-05-08 |      100 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-27 |      100 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-09 |      100 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-08 |      100 |       3314 |
| battery | 2020-05-08 |      100 |       3337 |
| battery | 2020-04-27 |      100 |       3337 |
| books   | 2020-05-08 |      100 |       3313 |
| books   | 2020-04-27 |      100 |       3313 |
| books   | 2020-04-09 |      100 |       3313 |
| books   | 2020-04-08 |      100 |       3313 |
```

Before adding `GROUP BY` for `created_at` data is like(column `c` has been taken with time for better understanding),

```
+---------+---------------------+----------+------------+
| name    | c                   | position | keyword_id |
+---------+---------------------+----------+------------+
| az      | 2020-05-08 11:48:01 |        1 |       3360 |
| az      | 2020-05-08 10:30:06 |        1 |       3360 |
| bags    | 2020-05-08 11:48:01 |       39 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-05-08 10:30:06 |       45 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-05-08 10:24:21 |       46 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-05-08 10:20:16 |       35 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-05-08 10:03:55 |      100 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-27 12:45:20 |      100 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-09 08:25:20 |      100 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-09 06:45:48 |      100 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-08 06:52:08 |      100 |       3314 |
| battery | 2020-05-08 11:48:01 |       14 |       3337 |
| battery | 2020-05-08 10:30:06 |       14 |       3337 |
| battery | 2020-05-08 10:24:21 |       12 |       3337 |
| battery | 2020-05-08 10:20:17 |       12 |       3337 |
| battery | 2020-05-08 10:03:55 |      100 |       3337 |
| battery | 2020-04-27 12:45:20 |      100 |       3337 |
```

Without `GROUP BY` it sorts in `desc` order. But my requirement is, data should be sort using `keyword_histories.created_at` in descending order even if I add `GROUP BY` for `DATE(keyword_histories.created_at)`.

Expected output should be like,

```
* With time, added for just to know the `datetime` to sort

+---------+---------------------+----------+------------+
| name    | c                   | position | keyword_id |
+---------+---------------------+----------+------------+
| az      | 2020-05-08 11:48:01 |        1 |       3360 |
| bags    | 2020-05-08 11:48:01 |       39 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-27 12:45:20 |      100 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-09 08:25:20 |      100 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-08 06:52:08 |      100 |       3314 |
| battery | 2020-05-08 11:48:01 |       14 |       3337 |
| battery | 2020-04-27 12:45:20 |      100 |       3337 |


* Without time, exact output required.

+---------+------------+----------+------------+
| name    | c          | position | keyword_id |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+
| az      | 2020-05-08 |        1 |       3360 |
| bags    | 2020-05-08 |       39 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-27 |      100 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-09 |      100 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-08 |      100 |       3314 |
| battery | 2020-05-08 |       14 |       3337 |
| battery | 2020-04-27 |      100 |       3337 |
```

`position` value is the main field to display based on latest `created_at`. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: I don't get it. What exactly are you expecting? So you want the final output to be sorted in the descending order of created_at, or ascending order of name and then descending order of created_at?

Comment: It should be order of created_at. Even if order of name is not there then also sort will not work based on requirement.

Comment: Also output should be like second one(without time)

Comment: In the actual output, there are 4 records with`bags`. In your expected output, there are only 3. Why is that?

Comment: Sorry! It has been updated.

Comment: I still don't get it. If that's the case then both the tables are exactly same right?

Comment: Both tables are same but only time is not there in second table(second column). I have added that for better understanding of what I need exactly.

Comment: I want data as same as second table(without time).

Comment: I am not talking about those two. The expected (last) table and the output (first)

Comment: First table is not sorting in descending order of `created_at`. Difference can see in `position` column.

Comment: Okay so you want the position value to be that of the record whose created_at is latest?

Comment: Exactly. Position value is required based on latest `created_at`.

Comment: Right,I suggest you add that particular detail to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214106/discussion-between-shruthi-r-and-vss-chaitanya-chavali).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested query, if it is okay.

See that second output you have given, which you got without group by,i.e.,

```
+---------+---------------------+----------+------------+
| name    | c                   | position | keyword_id |
+---------+---------------------+----------+------------+
| az      | 2020-05-08 11:48:01 |        1 |       3360 |
| az      | 2020-05-08 10:30:06 |        1 |       3360 |
| bags    | 2020-05-08 11:48:01 |       39 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-05-08 10:30:06 |       45 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-05-08 10:24:21 |       46 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-05-08 10:20:16 |       35 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-05-08 10:03:55 |      100 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-27 12:45:20 |      100 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-09 08:25:20 |      100 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-09 06:45:48 |      100 |       3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-08 06:52:08 |      100 |       3314 |
| battery | 2020-05-08 11:48:01 |       14 |       3337 |
| battery | 2020-05-08 10:30:06 |       14 |       3337 |
| battery | 2020-05-08 10:24:21 |       12 |       3337 |
| battery | 2020-05-08 10:20:17 |       12 |       3337 |
| battery | 2020-05-08 10:03:55 |      100 |       3337 |
| battery | 2020-04-27 12:45:20 |      100 |       3337 |
```

I don't exactly know how you got it. But I assume you have the query for that. Once you get this table, assuming an alias `T` for this relation the following query gives the required output.

```
select unique_obj.name, unique_obj._date,earlypos.position,unique_obj.id FROM
(
    select T1._date,T2.c,T2.position,T1.id from
    (
        select DATE(c) as _date,max(c) as maxc,id from T 
        GROUP BY DATE(c), id 
    ) T1 join
        (select c,position,id from T) T2
    ON (T1.maxc=T2.c) AND (T1.id=T2.id)
) earlypos JOIN
(
    select name,DATE(c) as _date,id FROM T
    group by name,DATE(c),id
) unique_obj

ON (earlypos._date=unique_obj._date) AND (earlypos.id=unique_obj.id)
ORDER BY unique_obj.name,unique_obj._date desc;
```

Maybe, you will be able to optimize it further by using the main query, but this one will work.

`earlypos` gets the required `position` for each `c,id` combination.

`unique_obj` is a simple projection of the table `T` with unique values of `c,id` combination.

I assume for given `c` and `id` values, the `name` is unique. Hence, I also put the `name` in the `group by` of `unique_obj`. Otherwise it would become a non-aggregate attribute.

The output I got is

```
+---------+------------+----------+------+
| name    | _date      | position | id   |
+---------+------------+----------+------+
| az      | 2020-05-08 |        1 | 3360 |
| bags    | 2020-05-08 |       39 | 3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-27 |      100 | 3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-09 |      100 | 3314 |
| bags    | 2020-04-08 |      100 | 3314 |
| battery | 2020-05-08 |       14 | 3337 |
| battery | 2020-04-27 |      100 | 3337 |
+---------+------------+----------+------+
```

which is similar to the expected output.
Comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Can you please convert it to my table's name? Its confusing.

Comment: Give me the query you used for the second table. The one with positions 1 1 39 45 46...

Comment: Above mentioned query is currently using, second table is modified manually to show the output which is required.

Comment: I know. But my method uses the second tables query only. So please send that query. Send it in the chat.